# hide subfolder using mod_rewrite htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how can i hide **project** subfolder in the two url's, i have tried many ways but nothing went fine

below are the url's

`mydomain.com/project/service.php?param=40&some/text/goes/here`

and

`mydomain.com/project/item.php?param=15&some/text/goes/here`

this is the code i have tried so far.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be so much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: This should work if you use `QSA` flag with `L` flag: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @JustinIurman seems like not working, mydomain.com gets 500 internal server error now !!

Comment: What's the redirected url if you add `R=302` flag ? Do it this way: `[L,QSA,R=302]`

Comment: @JustinIurman sorry i got 403 Forbidden error with out `R=302` and with that i got this `mydomain.com/project/`

Comment: Well i guess you're trying to access `http://mydomain.com/` regarding on that result ? What about this one: `mydomain.com/item.php?param=15&some/text/goes/here` ?

Comment: i tried the above link, and the page looked messy without applying css and script, and i can still see the project subfolder.

Comment: This is because of the redirection test. If you try again with that url and remove `R=302` from flags, you'll have it

Comment: It is still the same, and i dont find any change in URL, as i can see **project** subfolder !!

Comment: have edited complete **.htaccess** file, index.php rule might be overriding this new rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten your htaccess taking your comments into consideration

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# hide PROJECT folder from url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /project/(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [R=301,L]

# hide homepage index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]

# check if file/folder exists in PROJECT folder (if so, internally rewrite)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project/$1 [L,QSA]

# internally rewrite everything (except existing file/folder) to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, project folder name is hiding but the link is redirecting to home page.

Comment: Did you try to reach `http://domain.com/project/` ? If so, this is a normal behaviour. For example, try to reach `http://domain.com/project/something-new` and you will be redirected to `http://domain.com/something-new` (which will be forwarded to `index.php` since it does not exists in `project` folder). You can try the same with existing file/folder in `project` folder (will be forwarded to `/project/XXX`)

Comment: its working, but to my home page index.php isn't hidden.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add that rule. Do you want `index.php` from home only to be hidden or for every folder ?

Comment: i don't have `index.php` in `domain.com/project/services.php/some-text` or in other link, but i want to hide in **home page**

Comment: we have another problem, as i mentioned another link `mydomain.com/project/item.php?param=15&some/text/goes/here` its not working.
Actually its a search link, when the user search a data then that item.php will be opened, when the user gives Ir-relevant data then the page will redirect to noresults.php page. But here even if the data is available its redirecting to noresults.php.

Comment: I edited my answer. I've added code to hide *homepage* `index.php`. For the other problem, that's not part of my code. It's in your php logic, you'll have to debug

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/project/
 RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ /$1 [r,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/.*$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/$1 [L]
```

This will remove the `project` folder in the URL, and then add it back silently (the user doesn't see it being readded.

Comment: this has removed the project folder but i got **500 Internal Server**

Comment: This code will give you a nice infinite redirection loop